# I have ACE editor in a html file locally. How to get/set its contents from another html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If editor is located in the same html file, I can easily access the contents, but when it is located in another html, I seem lost.

New to Jquery, this seems a bit confusing.

A.html

```
<div id="editor">//your C code goes here
#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s \n","This is Sample C template")
    return 0;
}    
</div>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/textmate");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/c_cpp");
</script>
```

B.html

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function submit() {

   $.get("EA/editorC.html", function(data) {
    //cant do something

   });
}
</script>
```

Comment: for that you need to get the content on the same page then you should store it in a variable and then you can pass it by function or ajax call to the page on which you want to get

Comment: The only way I can think of is storing it in a div/text box, which I do not want :(

Comment: why you need to store it in a div or text box .? while you can store it in variables.?

Comment: you can use $'s `.load()` method to put the content from one file to the current one, then run your editor code when that div is filled with the new content. make sure to use http